# Getting my page to follow the textbar

Tags: jquery, input

Okay, so I'm working a text responsive game where the player types in their actions, the result pops up with each input. My question is how can I get the page to scroll down each time the textbar moves downwards on the page? I'm 100% sure I'm making sense. I've been having a hard time putting the question into words.

```js
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("form").submit(function() {
  var input = $("#commandtwo").val();
  var check = false;
  
  if(input == "help") {
   $("#Help").clone().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
   
 }
 
 
 if(input == "Obey traffic laws") {
  $("<p class='text'>Great idea! However, your competitors are speeding by in the yellow lane and your passangers are complaining. The next day, word has spread and no passangers are willing to use your taxi.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
   $("<img src='img/Fail.png'/>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(10000);
 
 }

  if(input == "Cross the yellow line") {
  $("<p class='text'>You like to live on the wild side I see? You're competitors all do the same but you are ahead of them and get your passangers to work on time. Great job, despite your law breaking ways.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
   $("<p id='green' class='text'>Okay?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
  
 }
 
  if(input == "Okay") {
  $("<p class='text'>Perfect. Now it's time to take new passangers back to Lombardy East via Alexandra. On the way you decide to illegally cut off another driver and it almost ends in disaster. What is your response?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
   $("<p id='green' class='text'>Give them the finger and drive off?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
   $("<p id='green' class='text'>Apologize?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);

 }
 
  if(input == "Give them the finger and drive off") {
  $("<p class='text'>Yasssssss! Establish dominance! You own the road! Right?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
  $("<p id='green' class='text'>Right?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
  
 }
 
 if(input == "Apologize") {
  $("<p class='text'>Pfft, you're such a wuss. You're no taxi driver!</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
  $("<img src='img/Fail.png'/>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(10000);
  
 }
 
 if(input == "Right") {
$("<p class='text'>Great! It's almost the end of the day and you have one final load of passangers to drop off in Sandton. Mid-drive, there's an annoying passanger causing some sort of trouble. How do you handle it?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
$("<p id='green' class='text'>Ask them nicely?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
$("<p id='green' class='text'>Turn the damn taxi around?</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
  
 }
 
  if(input == "Ask them nicely") {
 $("<p class='text'>NO! Establish dominance, remember. And you were so close too!</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
 $("<img src='img/Fail.png'/>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(10000);
  
 }
 
  if(input == "Turn the damn taxi around") {
 $("<p class='text'>Exactly! Just like we spoke about! Establish dominance. You know, I think you're pretty cut out for this life. You'll make tones of money! The taxi business all about showing 'em who's boss and commanding respect. I see you know exactly how this works! Great Job! This is just the beginning. The next stage will be even more difficult. Brace yourself for Part Two.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(10000);
 $("<img src='img/Pass.png'/>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(10000);
  
 }
    if(input == "Home") {
  var url = "firstpage.html";
  $(location).attr('href',url);
  
 }
 else if(input !="Obey traffic laws"){
  $("<p class='text'> I do not understand your answer</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholdertwo").fadeIn(1000);
  
 }
 
 
 $("#commandtwo").val("");
 
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Gametwo.js"></script>
<title>Lombardy East Day 2</title>
</head>

<body id="etoll">
<div id="everything">
<br />
<br />

<h1 class="text"> Day 2 </h1>
<p id="intro" class="text"> Alright! Lombardy East! The great thing about this location is that it's close to many popular areas. The best places near by are Alexandra and Sandton. Alexandra, a highly populated residential area and Sandton, the richest square mile in all of Africa where so many work. Great job choosing Lombardy.
</p>
<p class="text"> So your route will be Lombardy East, Lombardy West, Alexandra to Sandton. The traffic is hectic but there are no cops around. The other side of the yellow line is clear as day. What do you do?
<p id="green" class="text">Obey traffic laws?
</p>
<p id="green" class="text">Cross the yellow line?</p>

<p id="green" class="text"> </p>

<p id="Help" class="text">Make sure your spelling is correct!</p>
<div id="placeholdertwo"></div>

<form onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" size="50" autofocus="autofocus" id="commandtwo"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery scrollTop function (https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) by tacking this on after all of your ifs:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```

What this is saying is 'scroll to the bottom of the document'

I understand that your form may not always be the last thing on the page (if you have a footer or anything) in which case you could swap out the document height with:

```
$("form").offset().top
```

Here it is in action:

http://codepen.io/caleboleary/pen/WrbEGQ

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah! This is what I wanted to do! Thank You So much!Is it only possible to scroll the form to the top of the page or is there a way to get it to the middle of the page as well?